# Big numbers and floating point numbers in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, math

I have this Java code:

```
nextDouble = 0.2515933907977884;

long numerator = (long) (nextDouble * (1L << 53));
```

I would like to be able to produce the same output this line produces in Java but within JavaScript.

```
nextDouble = 0.2515933907977884;
const numerator = nextDouble * (1 << 53);
```

Has anybody got an idea for how to replicate a long within JavaScript ? I know there is BigInt in JavaScript but thing is, it doesn't support floating point numbers, so I am a bit stuck on what to do. Does anybody know any interesting libraries, that could solve this issue ?

Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is what `1<<53` does in javascript. It doesn't do what you think it does.

Here, try this in the console:

```
1<<30
1073741824
// okay.. looks good

1<<31
> -2147483648
// a negative num.. wha??

1<<32
> 1
// WHAA????????

1<<53
> 2097152
// That seems VERY low to me

1<<21
> 2097152
// How is that the same? as 1<<53??
```

numbers in javascript are forced into being doubles, and doing bit shifts on a double is utterly ridiculous. Javascript nevertheless lets you, because, well, javascript. When you do silly things in javascript, javascript will give you silly answers, and in that way javascript is rather worthless - programmers doing crazy stuff that cannot reasonably be interpreted as having any particular meaning should be answered with a clear error and not a wild stab in the dark. But that's just how javascript is. The usual way to deal with this crazy behaviour is to never ask javascript silly things, as it will give you silly answers. Such as `1<<32` being 1*.

You may be wondering 'but how is asking to bit shift 1 by 53 positions 'crazy'? - and the answer is, that bit shifts, given that they make no sense on doubles, are interpreted as: "You wish to emulate 32-bit signed int behaviour", and that is exactly what javascript does, notably including the weirdish java/C-ism that only the bottom 5 bits of the number on the RHS count. In other words, `<<32` is the same thing as `<<0` - after all, the bottom 5 bits of 32.. is 0. Said differently, take the right hand side number, divide it by 32, toss the result, keep the remainder ('modulo'). 32 divided by 32 leaves a remainder of 0. 53 divided by 32 leaves a remainder of 21, and that's why `1<<53` in javascript prints 2097152.

So, in javascript your code is effectively doing the double multiplied by 2 to the 21st power, or `theDouble * 2097152`, whereas in java it is doing the double multiplied by 2 to the 53rd power, or `theDouble * 9007199254740992`.

Rather obviously then your answers are **wildly** different.

The fix seems trivial. `1<<53` may look like a nice way to convey the notion of `2 to 53rd power` or `in bits, a 1 bit, followed by 53 zeroes`, but as syntax goes it **just does not work that way in javascript**. You can't use that syntax for this purpose. Try literally `9007199254740992`.

```
var d = 0.2515933907977884;
const n = d * 9007199254740992;
n
> 2266151802091599
```

so that works.

If you have a need to derive the value 9007199254740992 from the value 53:

```
Math.pow(2, 53)
> 9007199254740992
```

note that you're dancing on the edge of disaster here. standard IEEE doubles use 53 bits for the exponent, so you're at the very edges. Soon you'll get into the territory where 'x + 1' is equal to 'x' because the gap between representable numbers is larger than 1. You'll need to get cracking on BigInt if you want to move away from the precipice.

*) It is specced behaviour. But surely you agree this is highly surprising. How many people do you know that just know off-hand that javascripts `<<` is specced to convert to a 32-bit signed integer, take the RHS and modulo 32 it, and then operate, and then convert back to double afterwards?

Comment: Oh god yea this is very weird, uh that just super annoying. JavaScript is so beautiful :D Anyway I found some library called Math.js so far so good, I will try go on with it and see where I go. But thanks for this answer ! Update: Math.js can perform leftShifts on BigNumbers but not right. I think I may just abandon this for javascript this is getting super messy.